# Не работает метод, что не так?

Tags: java, методы

Пытаюсь написать код в котором метод `translate`, являясь модифицирующем (это важно), переносит созданный экземпляр класса `Point` на новое место в системе координат, метод не работает, почему и как исправить?

```
public class Point {
    private int x, y;

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void translate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(3, 4).translate(1, 3);
        System.out.println("(" + p.getX() + ", " + p.getY() + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Что выводит????

Comment: Что значит не работает? И какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: `translate()` у вас `void`. Вызывайте его после создания точки. Или см ответ ниже, что есть более правильным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте return this; в translare

```
public Point translate(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Как вы поняли что хочет автор?) мне нужно прокачать этот скилл)

Comment: 15+ лет experience.